# How can I draw a line and an ellipse in the same coordinate system?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

In this way, the x==y+n straight line and the x ^ 2/a ^ 2+y ^ 2/b ^ 2==1 elliptic image can be drawn to the same coordinate system.

For example：

```
x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1
```

Specific to the above ellipse and straight line

```
ClearAll["`*"]
eqns = {x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1};
line = eqns[[2]]
ell = eqns[[1]]

pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
(*ass=ResourceFunction["EllipseProperties"][ell,{x,y}];
params={a->ass["SemimajorAxisLength"],b->ass["SemiminorAxisLength"]}*)
params = {a -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]],
  b -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]}
glin = line[[2]] /. params
gell = b {-1, 1} Sqrt[1 - x^2/a^2] /. params;
gpts = pts /. params;
(*Plot[{{glin,gell}},{x,-a,a}/. \
params,Epilog->{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[gpts]}]*)

ParametricPlot[{glin, y}, {y, -b - 0.5, b + 0.5} /. params,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

The above code does not draw an ellipse and a straight line in the same coordinate system

###### 1. This is how to draw a single line, but the system will give an error prompt when replacing the value of b:

> ParametricPlot::plln: Limiting value -0.5-b in {y,-0.5-b,0.5 +b} is not a machine-sized real number.

Reference resources: [An answer by Daniel Huber](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278919/how-to-make-the-code-related-to-line-and-ellipse-more-concise/278938#278938)

```
ParametricPlot[{glin, y}, {y, -b - 0.5, b + 0.5},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}] /. params
```

The function of line range expressed by b is that the range of line y value is consistent with the range of ellipse minor axis

###### 2. The code for drawing the intersection of a single ellipse image and a straight line is:

```
Plot[{gell}, {x, -a, a} /. params,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[gpts]}]
```

There isn't any error in replacing a value here. Why?

Reference resources: [Comments by Alexei Boulbitch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279145/how-to-draw-a-picture-of-a-cross-cut-straight-line-equation#comment697194_279145)

###### 3. Now, how can I integrate the line and ellipse images into a coordinate system?

The range of coordinates is automatically adjusted according to the value a and b of the major and minor axes of the ellipse. That's why the above replacement is used.

##### Code Update 1

```
ClearAll["`*"]
eqs = {x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
(*ass=ResourceFunction["EllipseProperties"][ell,{x,y}];
params={a->ass["SemimajorAxisLength"],b->ass["SemiminorAxisLength"]}*)\
params = {a -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]],
  b -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]}
glin = line[[2]] /. params
gell = b {-1, 1} Sqrt[1 - x^2/a^2] /. params;
gpts = pts /. params;
(*Hold@ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqs},{x,-a-1,a+1},{y,-b-0.5,b+0.5},\
PlotLegends->Placed[eqs,{0.8,0.15}],AspectRatio->Automatic,Frame->\
False,Axes->True,AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{0.0,0.04}],AxesLabel->{x,y}]/. \
params//ReleaseHold*)
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs}, {x, -ax - 1, ax + 1}, {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[gpts]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.8, 0.15}], AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

##### Code Update 2

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqs = {x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, y == 2 x + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
p = Plot[y /. Solve[line, y], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.5}];
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}]
Graphics[{{First@p}, {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, {ax, bx}],
   Point[{0, 0}]}, {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[pts]}}, Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
 AspectRatio -> 1]
plx = Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}];
pls = Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}]]];
xpl = Collect[Resultant[pls[[1]], pls[[2]], y], x];
Collect[Coefficient[xpl, x^2] x^2 +
   Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[xpl, x], x] x +
   Select[xpl, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &] == 0
Collect[xpl, x, Simplify];
pl = {% == 0}
discx = Factor[Discriminant[xpl, x]]   (*discriminant*)
frist = Solve[eqs, {x, y}] // FullSimplify;
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {x, y} /. frist;
second = {x1 + x2, x1 x2, y1 + y2, y1 y2,
   y1 y2/(x1 x2), (x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2} // FullSimplify
thrid = {x1 x2 + y1 y2, x1 y2 + x2 y1} // FullSimplify
slope = CoefficientList[line[[2]], x][[2]];    (*k*)
intercept = CoefficientList[line[[2]], x][[1]];  (*m*)
Chordlength =
 FullSimplify[
  Sqrt[1 + slope^2] Sqrt[(x1 + x2)^2 - 4 x1 x2]]    (*AbsAB*)
area = 1/2 Chordlength Sqrt[intercept^2]/Sqrt[slope^2 + 1] //
  FullSimplify
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[Evaluate@{x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[eqns, {0.8, 0.15}]]`

Comment: thank you! I want to input the elliptic equation and the linear equation at the beginning, and then I will not input the elliptic equation and the linear equation for drawing and calculation, but directly use variables to extract. Includes the coordinate system x-axis y-axis range. It is better to draw the coordinate axis of the coordinate system. I have updated the problem.

Comment: ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[eqns, {0.8, 0.15}], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can be drawn to the same coordinate system.

Why not just use Graphics? Note that the Circle command can also draw an ellipse!

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = 4;
b = 3
centerAt = {0, 0}
lineEq = x == 2 y + 1
p = Plot[y /. Solve[lineEq, y], {x, -a, a}];
Graphics[{{Dashed,First@p},{Red,Circle[centerAt,{a, b}], Point[centerAt]}},Axes->True]
```

> How to add an arrow to the coordinate axis?

You can use `AxesStyle`

```
Graphics[{{Dashed, First@p},
  {Red, Circle[centerAt, {a, b}], Point[centerAt]}
  },
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> How to show the intersection of line and ellipse

You can do similar to what Bob did which is use `SolveValues` and then use the `Point` command in the Graphics. Like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = 4;
b = 3
centerAt = {0, 0}
lineEq = x == 2 y + 1
elipseEq = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1;
p = Plot[y /. Solve[lineEq, y], {x, -a, a}];
pts = SolveValues[{lineEq, elipseEq}, {x, y}]
Graphics[{
  {Dashed, First@p},
  {Red, Circle[centerAt, {a, b}], Point[centerAt]},
  {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[pts]}
  },
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the color, point size, etc.. as you want.

> How to label the corresponding curve with the corresponding equation
> in the image

One way could be to use `Text` command and place the equations where you want them

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = 4;
b = 3
centerAt = {0, 0}
lineEq = x == 2 y + 1
elipseEq = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1;
p = Plot[y /. Solve[lineEq, y], {x, -a, a}];
pts = SolveValues[{lineEq, elipseEq}, {x, y}]
Graphics[{
  {Dashed, First@p},
  {Red, Circle[centerAt, {a, b}], Point[centerAt]},
  {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[pts]},
  {Rotate[Text[lineEq, {2, .8}], 30 Degree], 
   Text[elipseEq, {1.4, 3.4}]}
  },
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}]
 ]
```

Comment: Circle command can also draw an ellipse.I remember this usage. thank you! How to add an arrow to the coordinate axis?

Comment: @csn899 added arrows

Comment: Thank you very much! This method can draw an ellipse! It's amazing！Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, {4, 3}], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

Comment: How to show the intersection of line and ellipse in the image. For example, the red dot represents the intersection of the two.

Comment: @csn899 updated for intersection

Comment: Which parameter should be changed when drawing a solid line instead of a dotted line?

Comment: @csn899  Just remove the `Dashed` from the code, then it will become solid, which is the default.

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
eqs = {x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, y == 2 x + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
p = Plot[y /. Solve[line, y], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.5}];
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}]
Graphics[{{First@p}, {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, {ax, bx}], 
   Point[{0, 0}]}, {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[pts]}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}]]```

Comment: How to label the corresponding curve with the corresponding equation in the image？

Comment: @csn899 updated for labels.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1};
```

**EDIT:** Intersections are at

```
pts = SolveValues[eqns, {x, y}]

(* {{2/13 (2 - 3 Sqrt[51]), 3/26 (-3 - 2 Sqrt[51])}, 
    {2/13 (2 + 3 Sqrt[51]), 3/26 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[51])}} *)

rng[var_] := 
  Insert[(#[{var, eqns[[1]]}, {x, y}] & /@ 
   {MinValue, MaxValue}), var, 1];

Module[{xrng = rng[x], yrng = rng[y]},
 Show[
  ContourPlot @@ {eqns, xrng, yrng,
    AspectRatio -> 
      (Subtract @@ Rest@yrng)/(Subtract @@ Rest@xrng),
    Frame -> False,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> Automatic},
  Graphics[{Thin,
    Arrow[{1.1 #, 0} & /@ (Rest@xrng)],
    Arrow[{0, 1.13 #} & /@ (Rest@yrng)],
    Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Tooltip[Point[#], N@#] & /@ pts}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! A small question, how to add arrows to two coordinate axes?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `Region` functionality:

```
Clear[x, y, r1, r2]
r1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, y}];
r2 = ImplicitRegion[x == 2 y + 1, {{x, -4, 4}, y}];
    
Show[{Region[r1], Region[r2]
  , Region[Style[
    BooleanRegion[And, {r1, r2}]
    , AbsolutePointSize[6], Red]
   ]
  }
 , PlotRange -> {{-4.5, 4.5}, {-4, 4}}
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Frame -> False
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesLabel -> {x, y}
 , AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}, {-0.04, 0.04}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@{eqns}, {x, -a - 1, a + 1}, {y, -b - 0.5, b + 0.5}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[eqns, {0.8, 0.15}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}] /. params
```

This code can show that lines and ellipses are in the same coordinate system, but why does this error prompt still appear

ContourPlot::plln: Limiting value -1-a in {x,-1-a,1+a} is not a machine-sized real number.

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@{eqns}, {x, -a - 1, a + 1}, {y, -b - 0.5, b + 0.5}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[eqns, {0.8, 0.15}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, Frame -> False] /. params
```

Comment: It's a matter of evaluation order. If you don't want to see it: `Hold@ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@{eqns}, {x, -a - 1, a + 1}, {y, -b - 0.5, b + 0.5}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[eqns, {0.8, 0.15}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}] /. params//ReleaseHold`

Comment: How to modify this code can be shown to the intersection of line and ellipse in the image. For example, the red dot represents the intersection of the two.

Comment: Please read Nasser's answer carefully。

Comment: {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[pts]

Comment: ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs, {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[pts]}}, {x, -ax - 1, 
  ax + 1}, {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.8, 0.15}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

Comment: Please read document of `ContourPlot` carefully by pressing **F1**, don't code blindly.